# What are some good fonts for User Interfaces? And what about Unicode?

Tags: user-interface, unicode, fonts

I am working on a user interface, and I am wondering what fonts do other software use like Photoshop, Windows, etc use in their interface. They can't be using Arial and Tahoma, right? This is a web application I am working on, and I can use @font-face.

But what about Unicode support? I would not like to put any limits on i18n.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some information on fonts used in operating systems:

- Windows 3.1, Windows 95, Windows 98 and Windows ME use [MS Sans Serif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahoma_%28typeface%29). This is a raster font, and as such it does not play nice with sub-pixel smoothing (e.g. ClearType).
- Windows 2000 and Windows XP use [Tahoma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tahoma_%28typeface%29). It supports a fair number of scripts, but some Asian scripts like Japanese seem to be absent. See also the [full list](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1805).
- Windows Vista and Windows 7 use [Segoe UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segoe#Segoe_UI). Again, here's the [full list](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1792) of supported scripts.
- Gnome uses [Bitstream Vera Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitstream_Vera), but this is probably distribution-dependent. A derivate font with more scripts is [DejaVu Sans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DejaVu_fonts).
- Mac OS X uses [Lucida Grande](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucida_Grande).

For a web application, I'd probably stick with the font that the OS and the browser use. Something like this will probably work for most users:

```
font-family: "Lucida Grande", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Segoe UI", "Tahoma", sans-serif;
```

I put the Windows fonts last, because many OS X and Linux users will have these installed, but we want their native fonts to take precedence. The reverse is less likely to happen.

Whatever you choose, use a [sans-serif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif) font. On a computer screen, these are far more legible than [serif](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif) fonts.

If you must use `@font-face`, be sure to read the font's license before you distribute it. From the fonts mentioned above, I think only Bitstream Vera Sans and DejaVu are free to use.

Answer (score 2):

Most software, barring major exceptions, uses the standard fonts that are determined by the platform. Windows has settings for the font used by window titles, buttons, normal text, etc. Users can customize these, and see the changes propagated to all of their applications (at least the ones that use common fonts).

Re: Unicode, the stock fonts on all of the major OSes have good Unicode support; I use Tahoma for IRC on Windows, and can view kanji, katakana, etc. and have had similar experiences with Droid Sans on Linux. I can't speak for Mac OS X, but I'm willing to bet that Unicode support is good.

Answer (score 1):

OSX uses Lucida Grande for all interface text.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Vista and 7, according to [this page of docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_(typeface)), the default system font is `segoeUI`.  Read the whole entry: it appears that you'll need other fonts to cover the gamut of languages...:

> Segoe UI includes Latin, Greek,
>   Cyrillic, and Arabic characters. There
>   are new fonts, also optimized for
>   ClearType, created for other character
>   sets and uses. These include Meiryo
>   for Japanese, Malgun Gothic for
>   Korean, Microsoft JhengHei for Chinese
>   (Traditional), Microsoft YaHei for
>   Chinese (Simplified), Gisha for
>   Hebrew, and Leelawadee for Thai, and
>   the ClearType Collection fonts
>   designed for document use.

Macs have been using [Geneva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geneva_(typeface)) for a long time (but as wikipedia says it's "not commonly available on other platforms", though the follow-on suggestion that "many find Verdana or Arial to be an acceptable substitute" would draw screams from many typography experts and fans (many of whom are in any case way bored with *any* Helvetica-inspired font anyway;-).

(Maybe it's time to propose a fonts-and-typography stackexchange forum?  there *are* some programming issues connected with fonts and typography, but they're hardly core to them...).